# Emacs shortcut keys to write-(un)protect a file in the buffer

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know what are the Emacs shortcut keys to write-protect the file in the buffer, and unprotect it?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Make it write-protected on the OS level or just lock the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-x C-q` calls `toggle-read-only` ([documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Read-Only-Buffers.html)). This state prevents that modifications are made to the buffer and the buffer cannot be written to the file it is associated with (if any), but it will not change the writability on the OS level (e.g. other processes will still be able to write to the underlying file.